# json_search throwing an error MySQL - #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql, json

I am using json_search to search the json formatted data from the column. For normal json data, it's working fine. But it's not working if string has a double quote. 


**MySQL Query**

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(user_information, 'one', '%name%', null, '$[*].label');
```

It's working fine for regular json data but it's not working for below data which is stored in the single column database.


**Data Example on which query is not working:**

```
[{ 
  "name":"John Smith",
  "value":"John",
  "label":"Sm"ith"
}]
```

Here is [db-fiddle](http://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8T39N3B4R8jZgn3vyG6cCQ/0) for this example.

As you can see in the data, for label key the string is `sm"ith`, I've just added one double quote middle of the string and then it's showing below error on db-fiddle.

> Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_search: "Missing a
>   comma or '}' after an object member."

But on my local host it's showing below error.

> ## 2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/49UDVFsyHEazRvC6Lyb25q/0).

Comment: @wchiquito I've reproduced the issue, it was not because of special characters, it was due to a double quote added in the string. I've updated the question. I also have created the db-fiddle, here is the link https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8T39N3B4R8jZgn3vyG6cCQ/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the double backslash escape sequence, see [Creating JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-values).

```sql
mysql> SELECT JSON_VALID('
    '> [
    '>   { 
    '>     "name":"John Smith",
    '>     "value":"John",
    '>     "label":"Sm"ith"
    '>   }
    '> ]
    '> ') `is_json_valid?`;
+----------------+
| is_json_valid? |
+----------------+
|              0 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_VALID('
    '> [
    '>   { 
    '>     "name":"John Smith",
    '>     "value":"John",
    '>     "label":"Sm\\"ith"
    '>   }
    '> ]
    '> ') `is_json_valid?`;
+----------------+
| is_json_valid? |
+----------------+
|              1 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks @wchiquito...! It's working fine, but is there  any way to make json in well format from mysql query?

Comment: @Onkar: From mysql query?. Can you give more details?.

Comment: @wciquito You have given the solution for checking the json valid or not that's working fine. But I want to go more in deep. I want to validate json which I can use above query but if it returs 0 that is json is invalid, then I want to make that json well formatted that is want to add \\ before that quote for that row in the same query. Shall I create a new question to explain in detail with eg?

Comment: @Onkar: A new question would be the right thing, giving details and example of what you need as a result.